# Cannot guess decreasing argument of fix for nested match in Coq

Tags: functional-programming, coq, totality

I have the following definition for terms :

```coq
Inductive term : Type :=
  | Var : variable -> term
  | Func : function_symbol -> list term -> term.
```

and a function `pos_list` taking a list of terms and returning a list of "positions" for each subterms. For instance for `[Var "e"; Func "f" [Var "x"; Func "i" [Var "x"]]]` I should get `[[1]; [2]; [2; 1]; [2; 2]; [2; 2; 1]]` where each element represents a position in the tree-hierarchy of subterms.

```coq
Definition pos_list (args:list term) : list position :=
  let fix pos_list_aux ts is head :=
    let enumeration := enumerate ts in
      let fix post_enumeration ts is head :=
        match is with
        | [] => []
        | y::ys =>
          let new_head := (head++y) in
          match ts with
          | [] => []
          | (Var _)::xs => [new_head] ++ (post_enumeration xs ys head)
          | (Func _ args')::xs =>
            [new_head] ++
            (pos_list_aux args' [] new_head) ++
            (post_enumeration xs ys head)
          end
        end
      in post_enumeration ts enumeration head
  in pos_list_aux args [] [].
```

With the above code I get the error

> Error: Cannot guess decreasing argument of `fix`

on the first `let fix` construction but it seems to me that the call to `(pos_list_aux args' [] new_head)` (which is causing problems) takes as argument `args'` which is a subterm of `(Func _ args')` which is itself a subterm of `ts`.

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`term` is a nested inductive type (because of `list term` in the `Func` constructor) and it frequently requires some additional work to explain to Coq that your function is total. This [chapter](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.InductiveTypes.html) of CPDT explains how to deal with this kind of situation (see "Nested inductive types" section):

> The term “nested inductive type” hints at the solution to this particular problem. Just as mutually inductive types require mutually recursive induction principles, nested types require nested recursion.

Here is my attempt at solving your problem. First of all, let's add some imports and definitions so everything compiles:

```coq
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.
Require Import Coq.Strings.String.
Require Import Coq.Strings.Ascii.

Definition variable := string.
Definition function_symbol := string.
Definition position := list nat.

Inductive term : Type :=
  | Var : variable -> term
  | Func : function_symbol -> list term -> term.
```

We begin by implementing a function that does the job for a single `term`. Notice that we define a nested function `pos_list_many_aux` which is almost what you wanted in the first place:

```coq
Definition pos_list_one (i : nat) (t : term) : list position :=
  let fix pos_list_one_aux (i : nat) (t : term) {struct t} : list position :=
      match t with
      | Var _ => [[i]]
      | Func _ args =>
          [i] :: map (cons i)
                     ((fix pos_list_many_aux i ts :=
                         match ts with
                         | [] => []
                         | t::ts =>
                             pos_list_one_aux i t ++ pos_list_many_aux (S i) ts
                         end) 1 args).     (* hardcoded starting index *)
      end
  in pos_list_one_aux i t.
```

Now, we will need an auxiliary function `mapi` (named borrowed from OCaml's stdlib). It's like `map`, but the mapping function also receives the index of the current list element.

```coq
Definition mapi {A B : Type} (f : nat -> A -> B) (xs : list A) : list B :=
  let fix mapi i f xs :=
    match xs with
    | [] => []
    | x::xs => (f i x) :: mapi (S i) f xs
    end
  in mapi 0 f xs.
```

And now everything is ready to define the `pos_list` function:

```coq
Definition pos_list (args : list term) : list position :=
  concat (mapi (fun i t => pos_list_one (S i) t) args).
```

Let's run your test:

```coq
Section Test.
  Open Scope string_scope.

  Compute pos_list [Var "e"; Func "f" [Var "x"; Func "i" [Var "x"]]].
  (*
   = [[1]; [2]; [2; 1]; [2; 2]; [2; 2; 1]] : list position
   *)
End Test.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly tell Coq which argument you are recursing on, you get a slightly more informative error message.

```
let fix pos_list_aux ts is head {struct ts} :=
```

Now Coq says

```
Recursive call to pos_list_aux has principal argument equal to "args'" instead of
"xs".
```

And if you use `{struct is}` instead, Coq says

```
Recursive call to pos_list_aux has principal argument equal to "[]" instead of
a subterm of "is".
```

The simple syntactic rule that determines if the recursion is sound requires you to do the recursion with a term that comes from destructing the argument with a `match is with ... end`.

It is not trivially ok to use something taken from the head element, as `args'`, or even in the case of recursion on `is` to use  `[]`.  For instance, perhaps you create an infinite loop where you call yourself with `[]` as the recursion argument.  The typechecker needs to prevent that.

The syntactic rule is "very simple" and does not apply trivially in this case, even though the recursion is "obviously" on a structurally smaller component in this case.
So you will have to convince the typechecker in some more involved way that `args'` is ok.

Perhaps someone else can give an elegant way of doing that?  My first try would be to see if `Program` handled this (but it didn't).